# Has the story《碾玉觀音》been translated into English?

Tags: literature

I'm currently reading《碾玉觀音》and whilst I'm aware that Lin Yutang has produced a translation, I've been told it's not particularly loyal to the original plot and therefore am not keen on reading it as it might distort my understanding. Can anyone recommend a loyal translation of the text?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another translator Yang Xianyi's text. Yang's family was a literati and a bureaucrat for several generations. Lin Yutang also was a famous Chinese writer, but Yang Xianyi was famous for translation and had already read many Chinese poets and Chinese legend stories even when he was young. Lin Yutang was born in China but got into American culture too early.

You can also find the autobiography of Yang Xianyi. There was a research article on the difference between Lin's and Yang's translation. Based on it, I recommend this translation. Here are some Links below,

https://www.worldcat.org/title/courtesans-jewel-box-chinese-stories-of-the-xth-xviith-centuries/oclc/1160311

[https://www.amazon.com/White-Tiger-Autobiography-Yang-Xianyi/dp/962996046X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/962996046X)